# Disable nginx logs

Tags: nginx, logging

How to disable nginx logging, without crit errors?

error_log off - doesnt works, just creates filename "off", really, not joke.

error_log dev/null doesnt supports.

OS freebsd. I need disable logging for subdomain.

Comment: Not a joke but I still laughed

Answer (score 14):

http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log

From wiki

> Note that error_log off does not disable logging - the log will be
>   written to a file named "off". To disable logging, you may use:
>
> `error_log /dev/null crit;`

Answer (score 3):

Set the logging to stderr (the redirect to /dev/null does not work reliably since from version 0.7.53 /var/log/nginx/error.log) is hardcoded to be used until the config file has been read (http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log).

```
error_log stderr crit;
```

Using /dev/null on systems where /var/log/nginx/* doesn't exist will cause nginx to quit.

Answer (score -1):

To disable NGINX access and error log for all latest NGINX version

```
  http {

          access_log off;
          error_log off;

       }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just creates a file called `off` and logs to that.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell This was answered in 2018. Probably logs setting got change with the new version. Please check your nginx version.

Comment: I'm on the latest version, `1.25.2`. It works for the `access_log` but not `error_log`. Documentation confirms this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log and http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log