# Disabling Nginx logging to make it faster - or other alternative logging methods?

Tags: logging, nginx

I am hosting a few heavy traffic websites, which are heavily based on Nginx. Reading about different aspects of Nginx logging (e.g. as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967388/disable-nginx-logs) on StackOverflow), it seems to already make a difference if logging is disabled (especially if there is heavy traffic. I am wondering what are the alternatives and best practices for slow hosts (or slow disks) with keeping logging enabled. What kind of alternatives (memory, redis, etc.) can be used to keep the throughput of nginx at a maximum?

Answer (score 1):

Yes disabling nginx logging can help you (**though not significantly**, until you really are getting huge traffic).

By default nginx will write every request to a file on disk for logging purposes, **you can use this for statistics, security checks and such, however it comes at the cost of IO usage.**
You can turn it off saving the disk writes.

---

But I would personally recommend not to completely turn off nginx access log writing. Just skip static files from access logs and log only actual requests, something like this:

```
location ~  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico|js|css|txt|htm|html|xml|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|zip)$     {
    access_log off;
    #Your configuration...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    access_log /path/to/your/log/file;
    #Your configuration...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! So is there a way to speed things up, like using redis or memory store to hold the access logs?